# Creature that should defend gods and prevent godhood

Tags: dnd-5e, dnd-3.5e, dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons, content-identification

I remember that there was a creature, a construct I believe, that was meant to prevent mortals from achieving godhood and defend existing gods against threats.

However I couldn't find its name in the 3.5e and 4e Manual of the Planes.

Does anyone remember its name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are thinking of the **Varakhut** from the **3rd Edition Fiend Folio** (p. 101-103). It is the one on the left: the one on the right is the Quarut from the same book. It is an Inevitable, a kind of Lawful Neutral Extraplanar Construct native to the Lawful Neutral plane of Mechanus.

[image]

> Varakhuts are defenders of the gods. While inevitables themselves do not worship any entity, they understand the necessity of these beings and know that their demise would bring nothing but chaos to the universe. They hunt down those that attempt to usurp the power of the gods for themselves.
>
> Fiend Folio p. 103

Comment: I don't have *Fiend Folio* handy to check the varakhut specifically, but inevitables are usually constructs, not outsiders. Modrons are the construct-like outsiders; inevitables are actually constructs. Also it would be good to indicate which of the creatures in the image is the varakhut.

Comment: Inevitables are outsiders in Pathfinder, not DnD. Inevitables are constructs in DnD.